# How to search a item name in tree view using with pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget

Here it is my sample program i want to search a item in tree view,when i click a search button that item only i want to display display in scroll area, i don't have idea about it.But i tried with model and set sorted method but it can't work.can any one please help me how to search item in tree view.give me any examples. Thank you in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class InventoryDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(InventoryDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        if not index.parent().isValid():
            painter.save()
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("white")))
            r = QtCore.QRect(option.rect)
            r.adjust(0, 1, 0, -1)
            painter.drawLine(r.topLeft(), r.topRight())
            painter.drawLine(r.bottomLeft(), r.bottomRight())
            painter.restore()

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        s = super(InventoryDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)
        s.setHeight(55)
        return s

class Inventory_Items(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Inventory_Items, self).__init__(parent)
        inv_obj =[{u'productPrice': 123.0, u'productSerialId': u'123458', u'productName': u'Renewal Application Form', u'productDiscount': 0, u'productdp': u'/media/ecommerce/pictureUploads/1546958016_35_admin_index.jpeg', u'productUnit': u'Quantity', u'data': [{u'product': 1837, u'product__unit': u'Quantity', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'123457', u'product__howMuch': 2.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 123.0, u'pk': 65, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': -11.0}, {u'product': 1837, u'product__unit': u'Quantity', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'123458', u'product__howMuch': 2.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 123.0, u'pk': 67, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': 10.0}, {u'product': 1837, u'product__unit': u'Quantity', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'123459', u'product__howMuch': 2.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 123.0, u'pk': 69, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': 30.0}], u'productPk': 1837}, {u'productPrice': 1760.0, u'productSerialId': u'1168', u'productName': u'Truth or Delusion', u'productDiscount': 5, u'productdp': u'/media/ecommerce/pictureUploads/1546959987_35_admin_default.png', u'productUnit': u'Kilogram', u'data': [{u'product': 2180, u'product__unit': u'Kilogram', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'IND-BOK-D-2016-TRUDEL-02', u'product__howMuch': 1.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 1760.0, u'pk': 70, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': 10.0}, {u'product': 2180, u'product__unit': u'Kilogram', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'IND-BOK-D-2016-TRUDEL-01', u'product__howMuch': 1.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 1760.0, u'pk': 71, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': 1.0}], u'productPk': 2180}, {u'productPrice': 240.0, u'productSerialId': u'1219', u'productName': u'One-to-One Follow Up Slips ( Qty 10 pads - 50 sheets per pad)', u'productDiscount': 0, u'productdp': u'/media/ecommerce/pictureUploads/https%3A//bnistore.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/323.jpg', u'productUnit': u'Quantity', u'data': [{u'product': 2185, u'product__unit': u'Quantity', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'123457', u'product__howMuch': 1.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 240.0, u'pk': 62, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': -48.0}], u'productPk': 2185}, {u'productPrice': 1500.0, u'productSerialId': u'3293', u'productName': u'Membership Application Form (Package of 10)', u'productDiscount': 0, u'productdp': u'/media/ecommerce/pictureUploads/https%3A//bnistore.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/New-Members-Application-Form.png', u'productUnit': u'quantity', u'data': [{u'product': 2225, u'product__unit': u'quantity', u'productVariant__unitPerpack': None, u'productVariant': None, u'productVariant__price': None, u'product__serialNo': u'IND-PRT-D-2016-NEWAPP-1', u'product__howMuch': 1.0, u'productVariant__serialId': None, u'product__price': 1500.0, u'pk': 66, u'productVariant__sku': None, u'quantity': 81.0}], u'productPk': 2225}]
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.le = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        search = QtGui.QPushButton("search")
        search.clicked.connect(self.search_item)
        hbox.addWidget(self.le)
        hbox.addWidget(search)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.inventory_widget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(columnCount=7,
            expandsOnDoubleClick=False,
            indentation=0,
            focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus,
            iconSize=QtCore.QSize(40,60))
        vbox.addWidget(self.inventory_widget)
        self.inventory_widget.setColumnWidth(2, 350)
        self.inventory_widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget {background-color: black;color: white;}")
        header = self.inventory_widget.header()
        header.hide()
        header.setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(2, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(3, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(4, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(5, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(6, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        delegate = InventoryDelegate(self.inventory_widget)
        self.inventory_widget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        c=[]
        for obj in inv_obj:
            it = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
            self.inventory_widget.addTopLevelItem(it)
            values = [
                obj["productName"],
                "Unit :  {0} ".format(obj["productUnit"]),
                "Price : {0} ".format(obj["productPrice"]),
                "Discount : {0} ".format(obj["productDiscount"])
            ]
            for i, t in enumerate(values):
                it.setText(i + 1, t)

            for v in obj['data']:
                child_it = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
                it.addChild(child_it)
                value = [
                    v['product__serialNo'],
                    "{}".format(v['product__howMuch']),
                    "{}".format(v['quantity']),
                ]
                for l, m in enumerate(value):
                    child_it.setText(l + 1, m)
        self.inventory_widget.expandAll()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def search_item(self):
        print self.le.text()
        #how to do search with item name(i.e like renewal)in tree view

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    settingobj= Inventory_Items()
    settingobj.showFullScreen()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the items that have the feature name and hide if necessary, if all the children are hidden the parent too.

```
def search_item(self):
    filter_text = self.le.text()
    is_valid_filter = filter_text == ""
    for i in range(self.inventory_widget.topLevelItemCount()):
        top_item = self.inventory_widget.topLevelItem(i)
        flag = (str(filter_text).lower() in str(top_item.text(1)).lower())  or is_valid_filter
        top_item.setHidden(not flag)
```

Comment: this is not work for me sir whatever i entered in search box based on that i want to show the results but i don't want to enter the full name in search field